# How to assign an image to 17 possible values ​in an object's key

Tags: javascript, if-statement, foreach

I need some help. I have to assign an image (stored in constants **iconOne, iconTwo**...) to each of the 17 possible values ​​for the icon key value of **const urlJson**. The 17 options are in the Ifs of the code below, as well as the const. How can I do this? I couldn't use if...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link id="mystylesheet" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1 class="city"></h1>
  </div>
  <script>
    const iconOne = ('<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">')
    const iconTwo = ('<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01n@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">')
    const iconThree = ('<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/02d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">')
    const iconFour = ('<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/02n@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">')
    const iconFive = ('<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">')
    const iconSix = ('<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/04d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">')
    const iconSeven = ('<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/09d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">')
    const iconEight = ('<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">')
    const iconNine = ('<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10n@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">')
    const iconTen = ('<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/11d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">')
    const iconEleven = ('<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/13d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">')
    const iconTwelve = ('<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/50d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">')

    const urlJsonString = $.getJSON('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=38.7267&lon=-9.1403&exclude=current,hourly,minutely,alerts&units=metric&appid={APPID}', function (data) {
      const urlJson = data.daily.map(({ dt, temp: { day }, weather: [{ description, icon }] }) => ({ dt, day, description, icon }))

      var htmlResult = '';
      urlJson.forEach(item => {
      // THESE IFs JUST RETURN iconOne
        if (item.icon = '01d') {
          item.icon = iconOne
        } else if (item.icon = '01n') {
          item.icon = iconTwo
        } else if (item.icon = '02d') {
          item.icon = iconThree
        } else if (item.icon = '02n') {
          item.icon = iconFour
        } else if (item.icon = '03d') {
          item.icon = iconFive
        } else if (item.icon = '03n') {
          item.icon = iconFive
        } else if (item.icon = '04d') {
          item.icon = iconSix
        } else if (item.icon = '04n') {
          item.icon = iconSix
        } else if (item.icon = '09d') {
          item.icon = iconSeven
        } else if (item.icon = '09n') {
          item.icon = iconSeven
        } else if (item.icon = '10d') {
          item.icon = iconEight
        } else if (item.icon = '10n') {
          item.icon = iconNine
        } else if (item.icon = '11d') {
          item.icon = iconTen
        } else if (item.icon = '11n') {
          item.icon = iconTen
        } else if (item.icon = '13d') {
          item.icon = iconEleven
        } else if (item.icon = '13n') {
          item.icon = iconEleven
        } else if (item.icon = '50d') {
          item.icon = iconTwelve
        } else if (item.icon = '50n') {
          item.icon = iconTwelve
        }
        var date = new Date(item.dt)

        htmlResult += `Temperature: ${item.day} ºC<br>
  Day: ${date}<br>
  Description: ${item.description}<br>
  ${item.icon}<br><br>`
      });
      $(".city").html(htmlResult);

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the object stored in the urlJson const and here is the icon key that I want to assign the image to in one of the constants:

```
{ dt: 1643803200, day: 12.84, description: 'clear sky', icon: '01d' }
{ dt: 1643889600, day: 14.56, description: 'overcast clouds', icon: '04d' }
{ dt: 1643976000, day: 14.85, description: 'overcast clouds', icon: '04d' }
{ dt: 1644062400, day: 14.41, description: 'broken clouds', icon: '04d' }
{ dt: 1644148800, day: 14.99, description: 'clear sky', icon: '01d' }
{ dt: 1644235200, day: 15.68, description: 'few clouds', icon: '02d' }
{ dt: 1644321600, day: 14.95, description: 'broken clouds', icon: '04d' }
{ dt: 1644408000, day: 16.37, description: 'overcast clouds', icon: '04d' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the issue above is that you're assigning values rather than comparing because you're using a single equal sign

`if (item.icon = '01d') { ...`  assigns `item.icon` to be `01d`

`if (item.icon == '01d') { ...`  compares the value of `item.icon` to `01d`

Secondly, instead of using a giant IF block, why not structure your code like this:

```
const iconCodes = {
  '01d' : '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
  '01e' : '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01n@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">'
}
```

Then, just reference this in your loop...

```
htmlResult += `Temperature: ${item.day} ºC<br>
  Day: ${date}<br>
  Description: ${item.description}<br>
  ${iconCodes[item.icon]}<br><br>`
```